# What is the connection between Guillermo del Toro and the video game Portal?

Tags: pacific-rim, the-shape-of-water, guillermo-del-toro

In Pacific Rim, the voice of GladOS from Portal can be heard (whether it was in the Gipsy Danger Jäger or the Hong Kong facility, I can't remember). Del Toro said he was a great fan and it was [a wink](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/01/07/del-toro-explains-glados-voice-in-pacific-rim) to the video game.

In the Shape of Water, I'm almost certain I have recognized the voice of the Portal facility being used again as the voice of the Baltimore research facility. I don't think I have seen it confirmed anywhere (I haven't spent hours searching though).

Is there really no other connection to Portal than Del Toro being a fan? The repetition of this easter egg makes me thing there might be more to it.

Comment: `Del Toro said he was a great fan and it was a wink to the video game.` What makes you think there was much more to it than that? [It's not unheard of](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/45631/why-do-so-many-movies-still-use-the-wilhelm-scream/85363#85363)

Comment: GLaDOS' voice actress also narrates one of the Pacific Rim 2 trailers, which threw me when I first heard it because I'd forgotten she was in Pacific Rim 1.

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't seem to be any other connection besides Del Toro being a fan and using the same voice actress in these movies.