# Where exactly is the “Wilhelm Scream” in “A Star is Born” (1954)?

Tags: sound-effects

According to this [other question and answer thread](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/85363/18230) that cites [this interview](https://www.wnyc.org/story/128898-wilhelm/) with Stephen Altobello, the famous “[Wilhelm Scream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_scream)” is featured in *[A Star is Born](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Star_Is_Born_(1954_film))* (1954); bold emphasis is mine:

> Whoever put it in the movie in the background for one scene, that's fine; that was probably expected. **But whoever found a way to weasel it into the arrangement of a Judy Garland song, that's somebody who really pulled off the ultimate, I think**, because the movie stops and it's the only thing that's happening. I'll never be able to pull that off.

##### So where is it? Where is the “Wilhelm Scream” in the 1954 version of *A Star is Born*?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's about halfway through (5:22) the musical number *Someone at Last*, used as an effect to illustrate an African villager falling.

Comment: I thought I was going to have to bump the volume and listen hard to pick the scream out. Both were wrong decisions. :D